# Pattern to get string between two specific words/characters using grep

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I need to extract email address from a string like this (I'm making a log parser):
`<some text> from=someuser@somedomain.com, <some text>`

with `egrep` (or `grep -Eo`). So the string needs to be pulled out only between `"from="` and `","` , because the other parts of log contain email addresses too, like `to=` and `etc`

Comment: Could you provide more sample text?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Using `grep -oP`:

```
s='<some text> from=someuser@somedomain.com, <some text>'
grep -oP '(?<=from=).*?(?=,)' <<< "$s"
someuser@somedomain.com
```

OR else avoid `lookbehind` by using `\K`:

```
grep -oP 'from=\K.*?(?=,)' <<< "$s"
someuser@somedomain.com
```

In case your `grep` doesn't support `-P` (PCRE) use this sed:

```
sed 's/.*from=\(.*\),.*/\1/' <<< "$s"
someuser@somedomain.com
```

Comment: Thank you. It does exactly what i needed. I didn't know about -P option. Will save this example for future using as well

Comment: This did exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: Will this work if the content to extract is spread over multiple lines (i.e. might contain one or more newlines)?

Comment: No, it won't match across the lines. You will need to use `grep -z` for that.

Answer (score 29):

Try `awk`

```
echo '<text> from=someuser@somedomain.com, <text>' | awk -F[=,] '{print $2}'
```

Here `$2` can be a different number based on its position.

Sample for word between symbols "(", ")":

```
echo "Linux Foundation Certified Engineer (LFCE-JP)" | awk -F[\(\)] '{print $2}'
LFCE-JP
```

Comment: This one's better.

Comment: I found this much easier to understand and use.

Comment: You may need to escape for some special characters for e.g. () and doesn't work directly. Need to use awk -F[\(\)].

Comment: I had to escape even the back slash as following when I wanted string between two square brackets:  `cat tmp.txt | awk -F[\\[\\]] '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 20):

A purely bash solution, requires two steps to strip prefix & suffix separately (but probably runs faster, because no subprocesses):

```
#!/bin/bash
orig='from=someuser@somedomain.com, <some text>'
one=${orig#*from=}
two=${one%,*}

printf "Result:\n"
printf "$orig\n"
printf "$one\n"
printf "$two\n"
```

Output:

```
Result:
from=someuser@somedomain.com, <some text>
someuser@somedomain.com, <some text>
someuser@somedomain.com
```

Notes:

- `${var#*pattern}` using `#` strips from the start of `$var` up to `pattern`
- `${var%pattern*}` using `%` strips from end of `$var`, up to `pattern`
- similar could be accomplished with `${var/pattern/replace}` (and leaving `replace` blank), but it's trickier since full regexp isn't supported (ie, can't use `^` or '$'), so you can't do (for example) `/^from=//`, but you could do in step one `${var/*from=/}` and then in step two, do `${var/,*/}` (depending on your data, of course).
- see also: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html

Comment: This is elegant. it's approachable for newbie like me, and I can fully understand it after reading it. Thanks for your answer!