# Bash include string between chars in awk print

Tags: bash, awk, scripting

I'm trying to parse a log file that will have lines like this:

```
aaa bbb ccc: [DDD] efg oi    
aaa bbb ccc: lll [DDD] efg oo    
aaa bbb ccc: [DDD]
```

where `[DDD]` can be at any place in line.

Only one thing will be between `[` and `]` in any line

Using awk and space as a delimiter, how can I print 1st, 3rd and all data (whole string) between `[` and `]`?

Expected output: `aaa ccc: DDD`

Comment: What have you tried, and how did it fail?  It seems like you should be able to solve this by reading about half of the first page of any Awk introduction.

Comment: `awk '{print $1,$3,$4}' file`

Comment: `awk '{print $1,$3, ???}'`, to print data at certain possitions, but I'm asking for help with including data between chars that can be at any place in string.

Comment: @TadijaBagarić, ok, show the expected output

Comment: @TadijaBagarić, so it is a single string not file, right?

Comment: It will be form a file

Comment: @TadijaBagarić: Did you look at similar questions before posting here?

Comment: @Inian I found a usefull answer here: `http://stackoverflow.com/a/21077990/3190306` but need help using it to get what I need

Comment: If you have `aaa bbb [ccc:] DDD` do you want `aaa ccc:` or `aaa ccc: ccc:`? What about `aaa [bbb] ccc: DDD`? It could be in field order of `aaa bbb ccc:` or it could be as you stated order of `aaa ccc: bbb`

Comment: I have no such instances in my file, but your solution will definitely come in handy!

Comment: @TadijaBagarić Don't edit 1 typo in a post if there are many more errors there, you are the reason the edit queue is full (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44024001/how-do-i-refer-a-control-or-view-in-an-item-of-listview-xamarin-forms#44024001)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***gawk***(GNU awk) approach:

Let's say we a file with the following line:

```
aaa bbb ccc: ddd [fff] ggg hhh
```

---

The command:

```
awk '{match($0,/\[([^]]+)\]/, a); print $1,$3,a[1]}' file
```

The output:

```
aaa ccc: fff
```

---

> ***match(string, regexp [, array])*** 
> Search *string* for the longest, leftmost substring matched by the regular expression *regexp* and return the character position (index) at which that substring begins (one, if it starts at the beginning of *string*). If no match is found, return zero..

Comment: Data that will be between "[" and "]" doesn't have to be at the 4th possition

Comment: $1 and $3 are mandatory? If data between `[` and `]` is at arbitrary position, could there be multiple entries like `aaa bbb ccc: ddd [fff] ggg hhh [jjj]` ?

Comment: Works great, tnx

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
$ cat file
aaa bbb ccc: [DDD] efg oi    
aaa bbb [ccc:] lll DDD efg oo    
aaa [bbb] ccc: DDD
```

(note -- changed from the OP's example)

In POSIX `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{fields[1]; fields[3]} 
                                {s=""
                                 for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                                       if ($i~/^\[/ || i in fields) 
                                           s=i>1 ? s OFS $i : $i
                                 gsub(/\[|\]/,"",s)
                                 print s
                                }' file
```

Prints:

```
aaa ccc: DDD
aaa ccc:
aaa bbb ccc:
```

This does not print the field twice if it is both enclosed in `[]` and in the selected `fields` array. (i.e., `[aaa] bbb ccc:` does not print `aaa` twice) It will also print in correct field order if you have `aaa [bbb] ccc ...`

Answer (score -1):

```
awk '$5=="[DDD]"{gsub("[\\[\\]]","");print $1,$3,$5}' file
```

or

```
awk '$5=="[DDD]"{print $1,$3, substr($5,2,3)}' file
```

```
aaa ccc: DDD
```

Comment: not sure, but code-only answers are generally frowned upon.