# How do I refer a control or view in an item of listview - xamarin forms

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms

I have a scenario like, in a `ListView` I have two Labels and a custom made horizontal List in each item.

Horizontal List - stack of Labels in a ScrollView with orientation horizontal.

What I need is, I want to refer a Label which is inside the Horizontal List of a particular item of the ListView and make the selected Label from the Horizontal List to Bold. Is there a way to refer a control of ListView item?

Below is the code for filling my ListView

```
myListView = new ListView
{
    // Source of data items.
    ItemsSource = itemsource,
    HasUnevenRows = true,
    RowHeight = -1,

    ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
    {
        Label label1 = new Label()
        {
            TextColor = Color.Black,
            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start,
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, new Label())
        };
        label1.SetBinding<LVItem>(Label.TextProperty, indexer => indexer.Name);

        Label label2 = new Label()
        {
            TextColor = Color.Black,
            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start,
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, new Label())
        };
        label2.SetBinding<LVItem>(Label.TextProperty, indexer => indexer.SelectedNum);

    //horizontal list
        StackLayout sLayout = new StackLayout()
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
        };

        for (int i = 0; i<itemLst.Count; i++)
        {
            Label label3 = new Label()
            {
                HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                TextColor = Color.Black,
                FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, new Label())
            };
            label3.Text = itemLst[i];

            gestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer
            {
                Command = new Command(TapL_Tapped),
                CommandParameter = label3,
            };

            label3.GestureRecognizers.Add(gestureRecognizer);

            sLayout.Children.Add(label3);
        }

        ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView
        {
            Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Horizontal,
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children =
                {
                    sLayout
                }
            }
        };


        AbsoluteLayout layout = new AbsoluteLayout();
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(label1, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(label1, new Rectangle(0.2, 0.2, 0.8, 0.25));

        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(scroll, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(scroll, new Rectangle(0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 0.2));

        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(label2, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(label2, new Rectangle(1.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2));

        layout.Children.Add(label1);
        layout.Children.Add(scroll);
        layout.Children.Add(label2);

        return new ViewCell
        {
            View = new StackLayout
            {
                Children =
                {
                    layout,
                }
            }
        };
    }
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ItemTapped to find which item of your listview is getting tapped. To get the text bold you should use a binding on your font. then in your codebehind you can switch the value of that binding and so will your font change.
Let me know if this worked for you!

Comment: Sorry for late reply.. I tried both ItemTapped/ItemSelected, but they are not getting triggered when tapped on horizontal list I have.. I think may be you have mistaken.. I want to refer a Label which is inside of horizontal list(I mentioned)..but not the Label of item of Listview..

Comment: ahh i understand your problem right now, i think. So the third label, where you added the tap gesture, should respond on being tapped am i right? this is basicly how I implemented my tappgesuture. `var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();

tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += OnTap;
            ChangePicture.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);`
the chagepicture is my label and in the OnTap i handle the logic that needs to be done(in my case a navigation input

Comment: yeah, you are in my way now.. and yes I have implemented tap gesture and I am getting the text in Label already when I tap on it.. but I want the selected Label from the horizontal list to be bolded also.